# How to query pull request by number, using Github's v4 GraphQL API?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I can query the *first* pull request like this:

```
query {
  repository(owner: "test_owner", name: "test_name") {
    pullRequests(first: 1) {
      nodes {
        id
        number
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But how do I query a certain pull request based on its `number`?

The following doesn't work:

```
query {
  repository(owner: "test_owner", name: "test_name") {
    pullRequests(first: 1, number: 50) { <-- CANNOT FILTER BY `number`
      nodes {
        id
        number
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pullRequest`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/#pullrequest) instead of `pullRequests` connection :

> Returns a single pull request from the current repository by number.

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "nodejs", name: "node") {
    pullRequest(number: 2) {
      id
      number
      title
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22nodejs%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22node%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequest(number%3A%202)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20number%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Compared to a `pullRequests` (with an s at the end) query, you just need to remove the `edges` and `node`  outer clauses, all the `node` fields apply.